# Android - imagem de ImageButton não é exibida

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, ícone

Estou tentando colocar 3 ImageButton em um LinearLayout. A imagem de fundo que estou utilizando são imagens drawable que adicionei clicando na seguinte sequencia no Android Studio (2.2.2): Botão direito na pasta drawable, new, vector asset e escolho qual o ícone a ser adicionado. Após isso adiciono no arquivo activity_main.xml um LinearLayout e dentro dele adiciono os 3 ImageButton. No meu design do Android Studio fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando executo um teste, seja no celular ou no próprio emulador do Android, fica dessa forma, os botões não aparecem. Apenas parte deles é exibida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo segue o arquivo acitivity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
android:id="@+id/myMainActivity"
tools:context="com.example.root.dtvplayer.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_surface_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:foregroundGravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical"
    tools:ignore="true">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/video_surface"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp" />

    <ViewStub
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout="@layout/activity_subtitles_surface"
        android:id="@+id/subtitles_stub" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_expand_less_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton24"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_expand_more_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton25"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_youtube_searched_for_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton26"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Onde estou me equivocando ?

***COMO FICOU COM AS ALTERAÇÕES SUGERIDAS***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
android:id="@+id/myMainActivity"
tools:context="com.example.root.dtvplayer.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_surface_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:foregroundGravity="clip_horizontal|clip_vertical"
        tools:ignore="true">

        <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/video_surface"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp" />

        <ViewStub
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout="@layout/activity_subtitles_surface"
            android:id="@+id/subtitles_stub" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutControls">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnUpChannel"
            android:contentDescription="" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnDownChannel"
            android:contentDescription="" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:id="@+id/imgBtnSearchChannel"
            android:contentDescription="" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Você está colocando os ImageButton todos no mesmo lugar, ou seja, você esta sobrepondo um embaixo do outro. Acredito que seja isso olhando o código xml.

Comment: Estou colocando os ImageButton dentro de um mesmo LinearLayout justamente para que eles não sejam "encavalados" um sobre o outro. O LinearLayout se encarrega de distribui-los de forma igual. 
Se eu fizer exatamente a mesma coisa com botoẽs Button, esse efeito de cortar o componente não acontece. Só acontece com ImageButton. Veja que no designer do Android Studio os 3 botões aparecem por inteiro.

Comment: a propriedade weight se não me engano tem que ser definida no linearLayout que voce abriu antes do imageButton, pois voce está utilizando ela nos image mas não está definindo qual é o total de peso do linearLayout. Não sei se ficou bem esclarecido.

Comment: tenta colocar essa propriedade na tag do LinearLayout... android:weightSum="3"

Comment: já tentou colocar uma imagem padrão do android? por exemplo o @android/drawable/ic_menu_add ou colocar uma cor sólida.

Comment: Fiz o que você sugeriu Felipe, mas não deu certo. Continuou do mesmo jeito.

Comment: testa com essa proprieade do ImageButton 
android:layout_gravity="right"

Comment: faz um teste. Ao invés de você setar o Linear como wrap coloca match e testa

Comment: Se não der certo Emerson usa o RelativeLayout.

Comment: É, com o match não rolou...Vou tentar com o RelativeLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifique os 3 `app:srcCompat` para `android:src`

Comment: Funcionou Rodrigo. Aplicando a sua sugestão e lendo a resposta do amigo @ramaral consegui o efeito que eu queria. Porém não pude usar o app:srcCompat, tive que utilizar o android:src. Por quê será?